# Vectorize for loop Python

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, vectorization

I have a nested for loop:

```
import numpy as np

ccounter = np.zeros(shape=(120, 200))
lat_idx = np.random.randint(120, size=4800)
lon_idx = np.random.randint(200, size=(4800, 4800))
for j in range(4800):
    for i in range(4800):
        ccounter[lat_idx[i], lon_idx[i, j]] +=1
```

This is obviously very slow. Is it possible to avoid the for loops and implement it as e.g. matrix operation?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: @warped I want to count how often the same combinations of ```lat_idx``` and ```lon_idx``` (the order is important) occur. In the example above I used randoms for simplicity. There is probably a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach with [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) -

```
# Get matrix extents for output
k = lon_idx.max()+1 # 200 for given sample
n = lat_idx.max()+1 # 120 for given sample

# Get linear index equivalent
lidx = lat_idx[:,None]*k+lon_idx

# Use those indices as bins for binned count. Reshape for final o/p
out = np.bincount(lidx.ravel(),minlength=n*k).reshape(n,k)
```

To improve the performance a bit more for large arrays, we can leverage `numexpr` to get `lidx` -

```
import numexpr as ne

lidx = ne.evaluate('lat_idx2D*k+lon_idx',{'lat_idx2D':lat_idx[:,None]})
```